# retrieve values of a series of $_POST keys

Tags: php, arrays, post

Let's say I have a series of `$_POST` values, all of them structured like `$_POST['shop_1']`, `$_POST['shop_2']`, `$_POST['shop_2']` (....).

I would need to join all the values of them into a comma-separated string, so at first I have to identify them. What would be the best way to do it?

The code might look something like:

```
foreach ( ??array_identify??("shop_*",$_POST) as $shop )
{
  $string .= $shop.",";
}
```

Comment: If you have control over the form, you can use field names like name= "shop[1]" and $_POST['shop'] will be automatically turned into an array in php

Comment: damn, didn't think of this one :) already made it with Marc B's solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [preg_grep](http://php.net/preg_grep):

```
$keys = preg_grep('/^shop_\d+$/', array_keys($_POST));
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $val = $_POST[$key];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `implode()` to join array values into strings:

```
$string = implode(',', $_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```php
implode(',', array_keys($_POST));
```

Hope it helps.